# JavaScript or Jquery - How to display last week of the month and next month's first Monday

Tags: javascript

How do you display only when it's the **last week of the month** (the text below).
The DATE that will be displayed here is next **month's first Monday**.

*"Due on DD/MM/YY"*

Answer (score 0):

To detect if this is the last week in month you can follow this example:

```
https://www.javatpoint.com/calculate-current-week-number-in-javascript
```

To get next monday, you can call this function:

```
getNextMonday(){
   var date = new Date();
   date.setDate(date.getDate() + (1 + 7 - date.getDay()) % 7);

   return date;
}
```

Comment: This is not what @xDiola is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below JS Code. It will show the alert on last week of month means from last monday of month.

```js
function Get_Last_Monday_of_Month()
{
    var year = new Date().getFullYear();
    var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
    
    var dat = new Date(year+'/'+month+'/1');
    var currentmonth = month;
    var firstmonday = false;
    while (currentmonth === month)
    {
        firstmonday = dat.getDay() === 1 || firstmonday;
        dat.setDate(dat.getDate()+(firstmonday ? 7 : 1));
        currentmonth = dat.getMonth()+1;
    }
    dat.setDate(dat.getDate()-7);
    return dat;
}
function Get_Next_Coming_Monday()
{
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + (1 + 7 - date.getDay()) % 7);
    return date;
}

var d1 = new Date();
var d2 = Get_Last_Monday_of_Month();
var d3 = Get_Next_Coming_Monday();

if (d1.getTime() >= d2.getTime())
{
    var datestring = ("0" + d3.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0"+(d3.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + "/" + d3.getFullYear();

    document.write ("Due on " + datestring);
}
```

Comment: If I change my computer's current date to 22/02/2021, the output will also 22/02/21 which is not correct. It should be 01/03/2021.

I think we miss something.

Comment: its okay na. because the next month monday date is 1 march 2021